# Cleanup after every junit class

Tags: java, junit

Is there a way to run a function after every JUnit test class in a suite? (similar to `@AfterClass` annotation in test

I know there is a way to add a listener to a test suite, but it does not know if its the last method of the given class, or not:

```
public class MySuite extends Suite {

    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.addListener(new MyListener());
        super.run(notifier);
    }

    private static class MyListener extends RunListener {
        @Override
        public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do in that cleanup function? Maybe we know another way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a super class, which does the cleanup on `@AfterClass` and then let all test classes inherit from that. I do that often for test classes which are similar, e.g. for integration tests which need some basic database that shouldn't cleanup afterwards.

Comment: thanks Chrisitan, though I have a lot of unit tests. I cant change them all one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` in your test suites but you have to use JUnit 4 Suites.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    //list of classes goes here
 })
public class MySuite{

   @AfterClass
   public static void cleanup(){
       ...
   }

}
```